# Equivalence of statements of criteria for Lebesgue measurability

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the equivalence of the following statements:

> (a) $\forall\epsilon,$ $\exists$ an open set $U\supset E$ s.t. m$^*$(U\E)$\lt\epsilon$.
> (b) $\forall\epsilon,$ $\exists$ an open set $U$ s.t. m*(U$\Delta$E)$\lt$$\epsilon$.
> (c) $\forall\epsilon,$ $\exists$ a Lebesgue measurable set $E_\epsilon$ s.t. m*($E_\epsilon$$\Delta$E)$\lt$$\epsilon$.

Now, I have no trouble proving (a) to (b) or (b) to (c). Here is my approach for (c) to (a):

> Suppose (c) holds. Since $E_\epsilon$ is Lebesgue measurable, $\exists$ an open set $U_\epsilon$ that contains E s.t. m$^*$($U_\epsilon$$\backslash$$E_\epsilon$)$\lt\epsilon$.
> Then, $U_\epsilon$\E $\subset$ $U_\epsilon$$\backslash$$E_\epsilon$ $\bigcup$ $E_\epsilon$\E  $\subset$ $U_\epsilon$$\backslash$$E_\epsilon$ $\bigcup$  $E_\epsilon$$\Delta$$E$.
> This implies m$^*$($U_\epsilon$$\backslash$$E$)$\leq$ m$^*$($U_\epsilon$$\backslash$$E_\epsilon$)$\bigcup$m$^*$($E_\epsilon$$\Delta$E) $=2\epsilon$

However, I am having trouble showing that $U_\epsilon$ contains the set E. As a side note, I apply a similar strategy for (b) to (a) (i.e., I cover the symmetrical difference with an open set $E_\epsilon$) and am having the same issue there as well. Intuitively, I am thinking because the symmetrical difference between $E_\epsilon$ and E, meaning $E_\epsilon$ approximates E and vice versa with error so arbitrary small, if there exists an open set $U_\epsilon$ that contains $E_\epsilon$, with difference in measure also arbitrarily small, then this open set must contain E as well. I am just having a hard time formalizing this as part of the proof (tried argument by contradiction but met a dead end). Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like an exercise from textbook on Lebesgue measure. There should be particular definition of Lebesgue measure in that textbook with some properties proven which would allow you to make progress. This question makes sense only at the start of exposition of Lebesgue measure, otherwise it is well-known property (regularity) of Lebesgue measure.